# How to render curve guided particles as path?

Tags: particles

The rendering setting is set to 'path' for both particle systems below.

- On the left, a Newtonian driven by a curve guide
- On the right, a keyed particle system

As you can see, only the keyed one shows path effectively:

[image]

Is there something wrong in my setting?
How to show path in the curve guided case?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally... the answer is in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/render.html#path).

> The Path visualization needs a Hair particle system or Keyed particles.